# Geth Stopped Syncing after Constantinople

Tags: go-ethereum, constantinople

The geth node stopped syncing after the Constantinople upgrade. Highest block I see is 7280001.

I did not think I need to upgrade geth, else my node will stop syncing if that is the reason. I can see on error logs `Constantinople: <nil>` which means geth is running with config which does not support Constantinople.

**Geth Details:**

```
Version: 1.8.11-stable
Git Commit: dea1ce052a10cd7d401a5c04f83f371a06fe293c
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.10
```

**Error logs:**

```
WARN [03-01|11:17:41] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=68677387327cf808 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
ERROR[03-01|11:17:58] 
########## BAD BLOCK #########
Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: ethash}

Number: 7280000
Hash: 0xeddb0590e1095fbe51205a51a297daef7259e229af0432214ae6cb2c1f750750


Error: invalid difficulty: have 2957101900364072, want 2958201410943272
##############################

WARN [03-01|11:17:58] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=589a0c5101eb2ea5 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
ERROR[03-01|11:18:15] 
########## BAD BLOCK #########
Chain config: {ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: ethash}
```

Comment: Exaclty the same problem here with block 7280000 (instance: Geth/v1.8.11-unstable-13af2764/linux-amd64/go1.9.4). Anyone has ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please upgrade your geth to V 1.8.20 or above. I have tested this with 1.8.23 and it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

I got the issue resolved by upgrading `geth` to version 1.8.23

Comment: It worked for me too. But I used unstable 1.9.0 from git repository. Not sure if it is a good idea though.

Comment: I always recommend for stable codes to be used in production. There can be some breaking changes when this version is stable. If in dev, you can always use unstable to experiment with experimental features.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The sad truth is that I just followed instructions from the bottom of the page: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installing-Geth#building-without-a-go-workflow. So I did not bother with the branch selection whatsoever. So now the question is: do I need to change the branch and get latest stable version instead of 1.9.0 unstable? What will happen with the current synced blockchain after geth downgrade? And what git branch should I choose to build from?

Comment: I am using 1.9 with docker and facing the issue